# SAS join (or insert) little table to big table

Tags: insert, sas

I have little problem. I have big table and few little table where little tables including part of fields from big table. How I can insert (or union) tables on the basis of if field is the same - set data, if little table not have field from big - set null/0 in big table.

Example:

```
data temp1;
infile DATALINES dsd missover;
input a b c d e f g;
CARDS;
1, 2, 3, 4,5,6
2, 3, , 5
3, 3
4,,3,2,3,
;
run;

data temp2;
infile DATALINES dsd missover;
input a c e g;
CARDS;
5, 2, 3, 4
6, 3, , 5
7, 3
;
run;
```

Is there an elegant method where if I insert temp2 to temp1 - missing fields in temp2 will set value of null in temp1?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what SAS does by default.

```
data want ; 
  set have1 have2;
run;
```

It will match the variables by name and any variables that do not exist (in either source) will have missing values.

For better performance when appending a small table to a large table you should use PROC APPEND instead of a data step to avoid having to make new copy of the large dataset.  That is more like an "insert".  The `FORCE` option will allow the dataset to be different.  But since the new data is being added to the old dataset any extra variables that appear only in `HAVE2` will just be ignored and their values will be lost.

```
proc append base=have1 data=have2 force ;
run;
```

If you really did have to generate an actual `INSERT` statement (perhaps you are actually trying to generate SQL code to run in a foreign database) you might want to compare the metadata of the two datasets and find the common variables.

```
proc contents data=have1 out=cont1 noprint; run;
proc contents data=have2 out=cont2 noprint; run;
proc sql noprint;
  select a.name into :varlist separated by ','
  from cont2 a 
  inner join cont1 b 
  on upcase(a.name) = upcase(b.name)
  ;
...
insert into have1 (&varlist) select &varlist from have2 ;
```

Comment: Big thank you for explanation, I like to acquire new knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear to me what operation you intend to do but some initial thoughts are:

1. To compare columns between two datasets (and check whether a value exists in one of them) it is good practice to use an outer join. You can do joins via `MERGE` clause in a datastep, or more elegantly use `PROC SQL`.
2. However, using either approach you will have to specify which two rows in `temp1` and `temp2` shall be compared - you are typically joining on a column that is available in both tables.

To help us resolve your issue, could you possibly provide the correct output for your desired operation, if you perform it on `temp1` and `temp2`? This would show what options you've explored and what needs to be fixed there.

Comment: Ah, I found solution.
it was enough to use
`data temp3;
   set temp1 temp2;
run;`

Answer (score 1):

you should try proc append.that will be more efficient because you will not reading your big table again and again unlike in

```
 /*reads temp1 which is big table and temp2*/

 data temp3; 
 set temp1 temp2;
  run;
```

/* this does pretty much same as above code but will not read your big table
   and will be efficient*/

```
proc append base=temp1 data=temp2 force;
 run;
```

more on proc append in documentation http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n19kwc3onglzh2n1l2k4e39edv3x.htm